# Implementing a "ViewHolder" or a cache for views for whole Activities

Tags: java, android, view

I have a couple of activities which due to loops and timers, often access the same views inside the layout again and again. I read somewhere that `findViewById` does not cache anything and always has to read through the layout to access and return the view.

So I thought about implementing something similar to the "ViewHolder" pattern which we are using to speed up our ListViews.

I come from a PHP background and Java is still very new to me, so my questions are:

(1) Would the way I developed it, benefit me in some ways? Or would the way I implemented it (using SparseArrays e.g.) hinder it to my cause in any ways?

(2) Seeing as I basically have the same method twice (`findTextViewById`, `findImageViewById`), is there some way in Java I can only use one method for that job? Just like the android framework is doing by utilizing `findViewById`? Because in Java the same method can only return a specific type and not a variable type.

My point with the questions are, that I want to absorb as much knowledge as possible and I appreciate stackOverflow and the wonderfull community a lot.

Thank you in advance.

```
public class ViewCache {

    private Activity act;

    private SparseArray<TextView> tv = new SparseArray<TextView>();
    private SparseArray<ImageView> iv = new SparseArray<ImageView>();

    public ViewCache(Activity act){
        this.act = act;
    }

    public TextView findTextViewById(int resId) {

        TextView retRes = tv.get(resId);

        if (retRes == null) {
            retRes = (TextView) act.findViewById(resId);
            tv.put(resId, retRes);
        }

        return retRes;      
    }

    public ImageView findImageViewById(int resId) {

        ImageView retRes = iv.get(resId);

        if (retRes == null) {
            retRes = (ImageView) act.findViewById(resId);
            iv.put(resId, retRes);
        }

        return retRes;      
    }   

    public void destroy() {
        tv.clear();
        tv = null;

        iv.clear();
        iv = null;
    }

}
```

usage from withing an activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private ViewCache viewCache = new ViewCache(this);

 protected void onCreate() {
   TextView text1 = (TextView) viewCache.findTextViewById(R.id.text1);
   // do something with it
 }

 protected void onDestroy() {
  viewCache.destroy();
 }
}
```

Comment: hehe what for? the Activity itself is ViewHolder ... if you need multiple time access to one view just make it a field in Activity class and set it once in onCreate after setContentView ...

Comment: The benefit of the ViewHolder pattern for AdapterViews stems from the fact that the child Views are often modified rapidly and repeatedly; i.e., when scrolling and flinging. It's a way to avoid numerous, expensive `findViewById()` calls. Since an Activity's Views are usually initialized only once during creation, I don't think you're going to see any benefit trying to use this pattern as you are.

Comment: But as I wrote earlier, in some activities I have loops and timers (it is a game afterall) and I access and change the same imageviews, textviews again and a again. Still no benefits with my approach?

Comment: @MikeM even for ListViews benefits ofvie holders are mythical, people have many problems with implementing them as they are not included in the system like in RecyclerView,  and if they do that the right way getView/findViewById is called only for new items to appear,  so if you have 100 items in your listview's adapter findViewById will be called only 100 times when scrolling top to bottom

Comment: @pskink I disagree. The benefits might not be as fantastic as some would posit, but there has to be at least some performance gain from only having to call `findViewById()` once for each of the, e.g., 10 rows visible on-screen (+/- a couple). And that's if each row only has one View to update. If each row has a dozen Views, that's just that many more `findViewById()` calls your saving each time that row gets reused. Of course, that's if it's implemented correctly, but that goes for any pattern one might use.

Comment: @Petros No. There's no upshot to searching through a collection to retrieve an object reference, when you can just keep a member variable with that reference directly available.

Comment: @MikeM. i just measured that on a emulator: i have a list view with 34 items, each item has 3 TextViews hence 3 findViewById per row, now i made 50 times scrolling top to bottom/bottom to top and measured the time spent in that 3 findViewById, when using System.nanoTime() the total was 23186267 ns = 23.186 ms, now divide it by 50, where can you see any benefit?

Comment: @pskink Sorry, but I'm not following your reasoning/methodology there. Anyway, our conversation has become irrelevant to the question posed, so...agree to disagree? :-)

Comment: yes, indeed its irrelevant...